# Digital signature with PDFTron for Android

Tags: pdftron

In the code of the lib there is a signature and a digital signature, but in the samples I could not see that there is the option to use a digital signature. For example when I open with Adobe Reader on Windows the PDF file "Getting Started.pdf" that comes with the lib there is a signature box, when clickling this you can add a digital signature, but doing this in the sample "Complete Reader" only shows the normal view to add a signature. So, if there is a code to add a digital signature to a PDF, is there a sample of it? or is this supposed to be implemented by ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digital signatures are not part of the CompleteReader UI, but they are part of the Tools library.  So you can customize the UI to add Digital Signatures.

You can also find sample code in the DigitalSignatures sample included with the SDK:

https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode.html#Sig